# how to parse the cellView.model inside paper.on('cell:pointerclick', function (cellView){})

Tags: javascript, jointjs

I am using JointJs and using the click event on each cell to popup the data from cell which was set while creating each cells.

Its showing `[Object]` while using `alert(cellView.model)`

each cell was created using

```
rectcell = joint.shapes.basic.Generic.extend
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer
var modelval = cellView.model.prop('attrs/text')